# abrir una base de datos desde la tarjeta sd de forma que pueda insertar o actualizar datos

Tags: android-studio

Tengo una pequeña aplicación (andorid studio) en donde hago consultas a una base de datos que alojo en la sd, no tengo problemas si solo hago un select, mas si quiero hacer un insert o un update me dice que la base de datos no se puede abrir en modo de escritura,la base la abro de esta manera

```
db=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(ruta+"/"+nombrecarpeta+"/"+nombre_bd,null,1);
```

Ya intente

```
db=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(ruta+"/"+nombrecarpeta+"
/"+nombre_bd,null);
       db=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(
ruta+"/"+nombrecarpeta+"/"+nombre_bd,null,null);
```

Pero es el mismo resultado, me dice que no se puede abrir.

La pregunta es ¿se puede hacer actualizaciones a la base de datos en una sd  o solo sirve para consultar?

Comment: y cual es el mensaje de error, agrega esa información a tu pregunta.

Comment: el  mensaje de error es: could not open the database in read/write mode.

Comment: Que sistema operativop Android usas? si es mayor de 6.0 requeriste los permisos manualmente de WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Comment: trabajo a partir de 4.4 kitkat, en el manifest agrego los permisos. tengo WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,